# exit out of an awk function

Tags: scripting, awk, exit, nawk

How do I exit out of an awk function? "exit" stops entire program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want the [`return` statement](http://people.cs.uu.nl/piet/docs/nawk/nawk_98.html).

Comment: I do not want to return anything, I just want to get out of there on certain condition. Possible?

Comment: Aah, I can just do "return" and get out. But that way we are returning some junk. Anyways I guess this will do for me. Thanks much.

Comment: @hari, returning junk is fine as long as you don't try to *use* that junk for something.